# How do I get both the abbreviated name and picture over the background (header) while not moving anything except the picture and text?

Tags: html, css, z-index

So basically I have been having problems trying to get both my image, text, and background-color in a certain place. But when I move one the other moves downward. They aren't in a class together so I'm trying to figure this out.

```
.Header {
    z-index: index 1;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 30px;
    height:2px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:blue;
}

#logo image {
    width: 600;
    z-index: index -1;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
}


#AbbreviateName {
    z-index: index 1;
    font-size: 40px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:1;
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

While my HTML code is:

```
<body>
    <img src="./assets/images/itachisignature.png" id="logo" alt="Itachi Eyes"/>
    <h1 class = "Header"></h1>
    <h1 id="AbbreviateName"><strong>A.L.C </strong></h1>        
</body>
```

I've tried using `Z-index: index -1;` , `z-index: index 0;` `z-index: index 1;`
I've also tried padding, margin, `position: fixed;` and `position: absolute;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things you were doing wrong:

1. `z-index` property values are numbers, you don't have to add text before them
2. `#logo image` this is not a valid selector. It should be `img#logo` which selects `<img>` tags containing an `id` of `logo`
3. `#AbbreviateName` id should contain higher `z-index` to remain in front of everything.

```css
.Header {
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 30px;
    height:2px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:blue;
}

img#logo{
    width: 600;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
}


#AbbreviateName {
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 40px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:1;
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600?random=1" id="logo" alt="Itachi Eyes"/>
<h1 class = "Header"></h1>
<h1 id="AbbreviateName"><strong>A.L.C </strong></h1>
```